# What might be stopping my laptops from seeing each other? They can both see a third computer on the network, but can't see each other?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, windows-11

I have a Windows 10 Dell XPS, and a new Windows 11 Dell XPS that I wish to migrate my files to.

Whatever I try though, I can't get either laptop to see each other.  Yet they BOTH can see my wife's Windows 10 work laptop - what could be the reason?!

Both of my laptops are on the default "WORKGROUP" domain.  Both have network discoverability and file/printer sharing set to on.  Both are on the same WiFi access point and SSID.  Both have been rebooted a couple of times with no change - can always see my wife's laptop, can never see each other.

‍♂️

Comment: Do both of their firewalls (wf.msc) allow WS-Discovery packets to go through, in both directions?

Comment: Don't know, but I do know I've never tinkered with the firewall on either box.  The older laptop (windows 10) works right now with a shared folder on another windows 10 laptop.  The windows 11 laptop is a fresh out-of-the-box install.  So it seems unlikely to be a firewall issue to me.  I've given up caring right now, and am using a USB stick instead.  A lot of comments I've found on guides to try to fix this seem to suggest that it's a known issue and MS has intentionally borked file sharing... ‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Make sure on both machines:  Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing and Password protected sharing are all ON.  Make sure Wireless connections are private, not public.  Make sure your Windows 10 machine is fully up to date and that SMB is current and not disabled.  File sharing between 11 and 10 works fine.

Comment: I had done all of those things John   Nothing I tried changed the outcome, sadly

Comment: Can the third Computer see the other two ? What are the 2 IP Addresses it is seeing ? Can you Ping the 3 IP Addresses between each other ?

Comment: You might need to debug whether Wi-Fi multicast is breaking for some or all of your machines. Discovery protocols use multicast (or sometimes broadcast, which is handled similarly at the Wi-Fi level), and lots of Wi-Fi AP and WNIC driver implementations are buggy when it comes to multicast handling. I'd have you test it by pining the "all hosts" multicast address of 224.0.0.1, but someone told me Windows doesn't respond to pings on that address by default, so that might not be a good way to debug multicast breakage on a Windows machines.

Comment: No idea what was going on, but two months later I've tried again and it "just works".  Just one of those things eh!